# Did Madeleine Albright say that "Siberia held too many resources for Russia alone"?

Tags: united-states, quotes, russia

I saw this quote [here](https://russophilia.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/hope-for-russia-america-relations/).

Is there any evidence, which confirms or refutes that she actually said and meant (it wasn't a translation error, she didn't later dismiss the statement) it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have read a lot about this. The answer is **no**.

[Here's](http://www.rg.ru/2006/12/22/gosbezopasnostj-podsoznanie.html) the source of this quote. Ratnikov, retired Major-General of the reserves of Russia's Federal Security Service, says that he "scanned" Albright's mind and found there this. He also found in her mind that she hates Russians and other Slavs.

Original quote from the interview:

> За пару недель до начала бомбардировок Югославии авиацией США мы провели сеанс подключения к подсознанию госсекретаря Олбрайт. Подробно пересказывать ее мысли не стану. Отмечу лишь наиболее характерные моменты, подтвердившиеся уже после начала агрессии НАТО в Сербии.
>
> Во-первых, в мыслях мадам Олбрайт мы обнаружили патологическую ненависть к славянам. Еще ее возмущало то, что Россия обладает самыми большими в мире запасами полезных ископаемых. По ее мнению, в будущем российскими запасами должна распоряжаться не одна страна, а все человечество под присмотром, конечно же, США. И войну в Косове она рассматривала лишь как первый шаг к установлению контроля над Россией.

It's only your decision to believe him or not. I don't.

Comment: ""scanned" Albright's mind - for context for those who can't read the interview in Russian: (a) The interview overall discussed Ratnikov's work for FSB/KGB **in the field of parapsychology and mind-reading**. The article's subtitle was "Секреты магии от КГБ"/"The secrets of magic from KGB"; (b) Leaving aside skepticism over validity of such claim absent some proof, one would assume that - if it was indeed true - he would NOT have been allowed to [yap about this classified stuff all over Russian media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Ratnikov).

Comment: Also, leaving even THAT aside, even the translation offered is incorrect. There was no mention "too many resources for Russia alone", and no mention of "Siberia" at all - the quote was "Russia has biggest natural resources in the entire world; and that upsets Albright; in her opinion, in the future, those resources should be not controlled solely by Russia but by *entire world*, under USA's supervusion of course". Abright wanting *entire world* controlling those resources is a nice touch there.

Comment: Also, for further thought: the same person [claimed on NTV program that information psychically received from aliens prevented WW3](http://www.ntv.ru/novosti/318484/)